# Cannot modify char array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, compiler-errors, mplab

Consider the following code.

```
char message[]="foo";

void main(void){
    message[] = "bar";
}
```

Why is there a syntax error in MPLAB IDE v8.63? I am just trying to change the value of character array.

Comment: A syntax error is a compilation error, not a runtime error, so this has nothing to do with modifying your char array. You just can't write `message[] = "bar";` with nothing between the brackets. It works with `char message[] = "foo";` because you declare `char message[]` then it assigns as `message = "foo";`

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I would like to know the proper way of assigning new value to character array. Thanks.

Comment: As i put it `message = "foo";` is correct

Comment: It is very important than you learn how arrays and pointers work, before you move on to string handling.

Comment: And memory management in general

Comment: You'll gonna like char* ...

Comment: 'As i put it message = "foo"; is correct ' -- No, that isn't correct, it's the blind leading the blind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot use character array like that after declaration. If you want to assign new value to your character array, you can do it like this: -

```
strcpy(message, "bar");
```

Comment: Previously, the "foo" shows up in my microcontroller LCD display(I have a LCD display will keep displaying the value of "char message[]"). I did include string.h. However, when I use the method above, nothing shows up.

Comment: See my comment above. Your µC is very likely a Harvard architecture. Here a list (non exhaustive) of µC using that paradigm: AVR, PIC, 8051, Cortex-M3 etc.

Comment: I checked, MPLAB is for Microchip, therefore PIC controller which tells it is a Harvard architecture with separate Instruction and data memories. You can not use `strcpy` for litterals.

Comment: I guess this explains it all. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Assignments like

```
message[] = "bar";
```

or

```
message = "bar";
```

are not supported by C.

The reason the initial assignment works is that it's actually array initialization masquerading as assignment. The compiler interprets

```
char message[]="foo";
```

as

```
char message[4] = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};
```

There is actually no string literal `"foo"` involved here.

But when you try to

```
message = "bar";
```

The "bar" is interpreted as an actual string literal, and not only that, but `message` is not a modifiable lvalue, ie. you can't assign stuff to it. If you want to modify your array you must do it character by character:

```
message[0] = 'b';
message[1] = 'a';
```

etc, or (better) use a library function that does it for you, like strcpy().

Comment: one thing weird about microcontroller IDE is when I try strcpy(message, newmessage) - newmessage contains "bar". It works fine. However, if I consider strcpy(message, "bar"), it fails badly.

Comment: If your microcontroller has a Harvard architecture then you will need to call specific functions (or even use assembly). On Harvard architecture there are 2 separate address spaces (RAM and ROM). A litteral is generally compiled/linked/mapped to a ROM address. Variables are in the RAM area. Copying data from the ROM to the RAM needs special instructions that the normal `strcpy` does not use.

Comment: The char assignement method works for Harvard architecture because the chars ('b', 'a') are compiled directly as immediate values in the instructions.

Comment: I checked, MPLAB is for Microchip, therefore PIC controller which tells it is a Harvard architecture with separate Instruction and data memories. You can not use `strcpy` for litterals.

Comment: `"foo"` is actually a string literal here. One of the initialization rules of the langauge is that a char array can be initialized from a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that only in the initialisation when you declare the char array

```
message[] = "bar";
```

You can not do it in your code

To modify it you can use `strcpy` from `<string.h>`

```
strcpy(message, "bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the character array like this . If you want to change the value of character array then you have to change it by modifying single character or you can use

```
strcpy(message,"bar");
```

Comment: I tried using this method but nothing shows up for the value of message in microcontroller LCD display. It works fine for "foo" previously.

Comment: @newbie You're not showing us all your code, which is why you're not getting helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
char message[]="foo";
```

This statement cause compiler to create memory space of 4 char variable.Starting address of this memory cluster is pointer value of `message`. address of `message` is unchangeable, you cannot change the address where it points . In this case, your only chance is changing the data pointed by `message`.

```
char* message="foo"
```

In this time, memory is created to store the address of pointer, so the address where `message` point can change during execution. Then you can safely do `message="bar"`