# I am getting an error of expression must be modifiable

Tags: c++

This is the struct

```
typedef struct struct1
{
    char words[kInputSize];
    struct WordNode* next;
}struct1;
```

I am getting error for allocationg memory block for block->words.

```
struct1* add(struct1** newHead)
{
    struct1* block= NULL;


    // allocate a block of memory for new record
    block->words = malloc(strlen(words) + 1);  //I am trying to add this line but I am not able to do it.
    }
```

I am getting E0137 and C3863 error of visual studio code in the last line

Comment: You appear to be writing C code. If so, please use the appropriate language tag. C++ is a different language, and the tags can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot modify char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396202/cannot-modify-char-array)

Comment: `block->words` is an array.   You are assigning to it as if it is a pointer.   An array is not a pointer, and a pointer is not an array.   Specifically, an array is a collection of elements.  A pointer is a variable that contains the address of something else.   The fact that pointers and arrays can be used interchangeably *in some circumstances* does not mean they are the same thing.    One difference - resulting from them being different things - is that pointers can be assigned (`const` qualifiers and the type system permitting) and arrays cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your posted `struct1`, `words` is declared like this:

```
char words[kInputSize];
```

... and then you try to set it equal to a pointer, here:

```
block->words = malloc(strlen(words) + 1);
```

This doesn't work because in C++ (or C for that matter) you are not allowed to set an array equal to a pointer.

If you want to be able to set `words` equal to a pointer (as returned by `malloc()`) you would need to declare it as a pointer inside the struct, instead:

```
char * words;
```

If, on the other hand, you really just want to copy over the string-data from `words` into the existing char-array at `block->words`, one way to do that would be:

```
#include <cstring>

[...]

strncpy(block->words, words, sizeof(block->words));
```

(Note that the `sizeof(block->words)` invocation to determine the number of bytes in the char-array only works when `block->words` is declared as a char-array; if you change it to `char * words` as suggested above, then `sizeof(block->words)` will then return either 4 or 8 [depending on the size of a pointer on your system] and that is almost certainly not what you want)